# Cmake link libmapnik c++

Tags: c++, cmake, mapnik

I am unable to connect Mapnik via cmake to my application.

I tried to do like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(MapnikTest)

set(MAPNIK_LIB "/usr/local/lib/libmapnik.so.3.1.0") dont work

#set(MAPNIK_LIB "/usr/local/lib/libmapnik.so") dont work

set(MAPNIK_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/include/mapnik")  work

#find_package(mapnik REQUIRED) dont work

#find_package(Mapnik REQUIRED) dont work

include_directories(${MAPNIK_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MAPNIK_LIB})
```

The thing is, I don't have mapnikConfig.cmake in /usr/local/bin/cmake

Can't connect the library directly. Include he sees.
I edited already LD_LIBRARY_PATH it didn't help either.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MapnikTest.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `mapnik::Map::Map(int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `mapnik::load_map(mapnik::Map&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `void mapnik::save_to_file<mapnik::image<mapnik::rgba8_t> >(mapnik::image<mapnik::rgba8_t> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MapnikTest.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `icu_66::UnicodeString::hashCode() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK6icu_6613UnicodeString8hashCodeEv[_ZNK6icu_6613UnicodeString8hashCodeEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `icu_66::UnicodeString::doHashCode() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MapnikTest.dir/build.make:104: MapnikTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/MapnikTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

[image]

(dont work mean this)
[image]

Comment: Doed mapnik come with a `MapnikConfig.cmake` (or similar file -- look in your filesystem) ? Then `find_package(Mapnik)` should just work. You don't indicate whether that works. Typically Config files live under /usr/local/lib/cmake, not bin.

Comment: If it doesn't have a Config file, then you need to create a FindMapnik module yourself. Search for one -- you're probably not the only user.

Comment: Finally, if you have a full path to the library, you still need to `target_link_libraries()` to link it to your executable; you don't post enough of the build message to see if that's actually happening.

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot I already checked the whole filesystem. I don't have this config.
I'm trying to write it myself, but I don't have much experience with it.
I will also try to download another version of libmapnik now, I found differences in my version and the version from github. Maybe I don't have -dev

Comment: I edited the post due to the comments

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You provided comments "do not work". This doesn't mean anything. When something doesn't work it should be explained exactly what is manifestation of problem (what error is reported).

Comment: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/demo/c%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt#L8

Comment: @MarekR i add photo

Comment: [Again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) do not provide code or logs as photo. You can copy paste logs - even it should be easier for you to paste tekst.

Comment: @MarekR   Target "MapnikTest" links to target "mapnik::agg" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_executable):
  Target "MapnikTest" links to target "mapnik::mapnik" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?  i use code from this https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/demo/c%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt#L8

Comment: This error means that library is not properly installed. Did you compile it yourself or did you used system package manager?

Comment: @MarekR ./configurate
make -j8
make install
I have installed includes and libs in /usr/local/

Comment: build & install mapnik with CMake instead of their configure script (which seems to call scons under the hood, so no CMake config file). There is no CMakeLists in 3.1.0 actually, it's part of master branch but no tag for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
When I inspect github more carefully it turn out that cmake config was [introduced recently](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/pull/4191), after [last release](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/tree/v3.1.0). So my answer will become valid for next release of this library.

You can inspect this change to see how import that library.

**Original (valid after next release `3.2`):**
Based on demo form [Mapnik repo](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/demo/c%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt#L8) it should go like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(MapnikTest)
find_package(mapnik REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE mapnik::agg mapnik::mapnik)
```

Didn't test it, but should work. I can see library [provides proper config](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/79901e494b759673417591866416e702567e5506/cmake/MapnikExport.cmake#L11-L16).

Comment: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mapnik" with any
  of the following names:

    mapnikConfig.cmake
    mapnik-config.cmake

Comment: @VolkKiiroi see update. Sadly my answer will become valid in a future :(.

Answer (score 0):

Find where you have mapnikConfig.cmake or mapnik-config.cmake and set `mapnik_DIR` to it. Like this:

```
cmake -Dmapnik_DIR="/path/to/config" ..
```

and it should be

```
find_package(mapnik REQUIRED)
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't have mapnikConfig.cmake.